# Multiple modal closing not working

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

Modals,
I am trying my best to implement them in my website.
I have 6 images, 3 in each row, total 2 rows.

I want to enlarge a image so that it centered and in middle of screen, in modal, but I have a problem with multiple image modals. I have tried to make scripts for each of them, but its too much of weird code. I get lost all the time in those codes. Maybe anyone know the code to show images in modal for 6 different images. when I onclick on image, the modal with that image enlarged will open?
Thanks!

I tried this version

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event){
  if (event.target == modal){
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

but when i added more modals, it started to get weird, by not closing modals ect.
Thanks for help :)